# PACF and ACF graphs not showing

Tags: python, charts, line, partial

```
#I successfully converted dates to date format that is proper for time series.
#Turn 'variable' column data into dates
homeprice['variable'] = pd.to_datetime(homeprice['variable'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
homeprice

#Did some further cleaning and column name changing - not including code

#This block worked as expected and created a simple time series'able data frame for me
homepriceTS = homeprice.set_index('date').rolling(2).mean()
homepriceTS.head()

#Remove NaN's from the dataframe
homepriceTS.dropna(inplace=True)
homepriceTS.head()

#tested for stationarity (it was not stationary). not including code for brevity

#There is clearly an upward trend in the line chart, which breaks stationarity rules. So lets transform with log
homepriceTS_log = np.log(homepriceTS)
plt.plot(homepriceTS_log)

#In this approach, we take average of ‘k’ consecutive values depending on the frequency of time series. Here we can take the average over the past 1 year, i.e. last 12 values. Pandas has specific functions defined for determining rolling statistics.
moving_avg = pd.rolling_mean(homepriceTS_log,12)
plt.plot(homepriceTS_log)
plt.plot(moving_avg, color='red')

#The red line above shows the rolling mean. Lets subtract this from the original series. Note that since we are taking average of last 12 values, rolling mean is not defined for first 11 values
homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff = homepriceTS_log - moving_avg
homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff.head(n=12)

#Drop the first 11 NaN rows since we chose a 12 month roll. Then we'll test for stationarity again.
homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff.dropna(inplace=True)
homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff.head()

#tested for stationarity again. It was much better, so I'll go with it.

#homepriceTS_log_diff = homepriceTS_log - homepriceTS_log.shift()
plt.plot(homepriceTS_log_diff)

#ACF and PACF plots:
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf, pacf

# I wanted to use method = 'ols'... but it just kept throwing me errors so I gave up and used 'yw' (not even sure if that makes sense to do in this case)
lag_acf = acf(homepriceTS_log_diff, nlags=12)
lag_pacf = pacf(homepriceTS_log_diff, nlags=12, method='yw')
```

## ----------HERE IS WHERE I START TO HAVE PROBLEMS-----------

```
#Plot ACF: 
plt.subplot(121)
plt.plot(lag_acf)
#plt.axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
plt.axhline(y=0,linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.title('Autocorrelation Function')

#Plot PACF:
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(lag_pacf)
#plt.axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
plt.axhline(y=0,linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=-1.96/np.sqrt(len(homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.axhline(y=1.96/np.sqrt(len(homepriceTS_log_moving_avg_diff)),linestyle='--',color='gray')
plt.title('Partial Autocorrelation Function')
plt.tight_layout()`
```

I'm performing a time series analysis and am running my ACF (Autocorrelation Function) and PACF (Partial Autocorrelation Function). When I plot them I get a blank graph to show up with the upper limit, lower limit and zero... but no line plot. I assume either the code for the line graph isn't working, or my window size for the ACF and PACF plots need to be changed (which I can't find anywhere on google or in the shift+tab instructions in python). Doe anybody know how I can get the lines to show up on the graph?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use the plot_acf() function and specify the lags.  In this case, I have the time as an index and the series is called `Thousands of Passengers` from the `airline_passengers.csv` dataset.

```
# import the plotting functions for act and pacf  
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
plot_acf(df1['Thousands of Passengers'], lags=40);
```